# Creating an association between two entities

Tags: entity-framework

In DB we have tables `MyTable1` and `MyTable2` and no relationship exist between them. In EF we have an option to create an association between the two entities `Entity1` ( mapped to `MyTable1` ) and `Entity2` ( mapped to `MyTable2` ).

a) I know it's kind of a vague question,but still ...  is there a situation where it would make sense to create an association ( either an independent or foreign key association ) between `Entity1` and `Entity2`, even though the `MyTable1` and `MyTable2` have no relationship?

b) When creating an association between `Entity1` and `Entity2`, we are also presented with `"Add foreign key properties to Entity2"` option, which adds a foreign key property to `Entity2`.  But why would we want to add a foreign key property to `Entity2`, if we can't map this property to any of `MyTable2` columns?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

a) I have added an associations between a Table and a View entity. The View was just a subset of a table so I thought it was appropriate to add an association between the two.

Comment: Did you add foreign key or independent association?

Comment: @user702769 - It was an association

Comment: just to be sure - it was an independent association?